# Node.js Express JS - Cannot find module './config/express'

Tags: node.js, express

Im Learning to make a web application with Node.js Express JS.

When I run my server.js

```
$ node server
```

I get this

```
Error: Cannot find module './config/express'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/david/Desktop/Node/ejemplo/server.js:2:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

my server.js file is like this...

server.js:

```
var express = require('./config/express');
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

before doing this I run this command in the root of my app

```
npm install
```

Here is a like to a picture to show you the [project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO69D.png) I have.

I dont understand why cannot find module './config/express' while apparently the folder structure is fine.

Any idea??

I dont understand why cannot find module './config/express' while apparently the folder structure is fine.

Comment: var express = require('express'); try this

Comment: changing that, the server runs, but is not referencing config/express.js like I intended to. how can i do that?

Comment: depends what are you returning from config/express

Comment: @DanielMontero if possible can you share the GitHub link if it is a personal project ?

Answer (score 0):

after installing npm, you should try express installation into your project directory as

```
npm install express
```

it will create node_modules of express.
then you should use

```
var express = require('express');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `server.js` doesn't work because `express.js` file into config folder create confusion.
Change the name from `express.js` to `init.express.js` 
and then it will work.